# how to not automatically exit from python command line following syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question is simply how not to automatically exit the program whenever it sees a syntax error so I can see the error message. I basically open myFile.py and it has got syntax error. When opened using the default program (python command line) it gives the error message in a blink and exits. It's really hard for me to see what the error message is.

Answer (score 4):

Run the script from the console instead of double clicking the script (run the console from the Start menu, type the path to the script and hit ENTER), or use IDLE to run it.

Comment: If 3.3's `py` launcher is installed and associated with the .py file extension, then for testing you can add `-i` to the shebang on the first line, e.g. `#!python3 -i`. That'll keep the console open in interactive mode without having to run the cmd shell first.